# If I call Twitter API to get all of my followers, how many calls to the API is that?

Tags: twitter

If I want to download a list of all of my followers by calling the twitter API, how many calls is it? Is it one call or is it the number of followers I have?

Thanks!

Sriram

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you just need the IDs of your followers, you can specify:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?screen_name=yourScreenName&cursor=-1
```

The documentation for this call is [here](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/friends/ids). This call will return up to 5,000 follower IDs per call, and you'll have to keep track of the *cursor* value on each call.  If you have less than 5,000 followers, you can omit the *cursor* parameter.

If, however, you need to get the full details for all your followers, you will need to make some additional API calls.

I recommend using *statuses/followers* to fetch the follower profiles since you can request up to 100 profiles per API call.

When using *[statuses/followers](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/followers)*, you just specify which user's followers you wish to fetch.  The results are returned in the order that the followers followed the specified user. This method does *not* require authentication, however it does use a cursor, so you'll need manage the *cursor* ID for each call.  Here's an example:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/followers.json?screen_name=yourScreenName&cursor=-1
```

Alternatively, you can user *[users/lookup](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/lookup)* to fetch the follower profiles by specifying a comma-separated list of user IDs. You *must* authenticate in order to make this request, but you can fetch any user profiles you want -- not just those that are following the specified user. An example call would be:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id=123123,5235235,456243,4534563
```

So, if you had 2,000 followers, you would use just one call to obtain all of your follower IDs via *followers/ids*, if that was all you needed. If you needed the full profiles, you would burn 20 calls using *statuses/followers*, and you would use 21 calls when alternatively using *users/lookup* due to the additional call to *followers/ids* necessary to fetch the IDs.

*Note that for all Twitter API calls, I recommend using JSON since it is a much more lightweight document format than XML. You will typically transfer only about 1/3 to 1/2 as much data over the wire, and I find that (in my experience) Twitter times-out less often when serving JSON.*

Comment: Update:  `statuses/followers` is deprecated as of May (17th?) 2013 Twitter.

Comment: This answer is no longer relevant. Twitter REST api is inactive.

Answer (score 3):

http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/followers/ids

Reading this, it looks like it should only be 1 call since you're just pulling back an xml or json page. Unless you have more than 5000 followers, in which case you would have to make a call for each page of the paginated values.